# How to lock a member variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have simplified this code for example purposes:

```
class TextLogger : IDisposable
{
    private FileStream m_FileStream;
    private StreamWriter m_StreamWriter;

    void CreateNewLogFile()
    {
          //Open the File
       m_FileStream = File.Open(
           m_CurrentFileName,
           FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
           FileAccess.Write,
           FileShare.Read );

       m_StreamWriter = new StreamWriter( m_FileStream );
       ....
    }
}
```

I get an `InvalidArgumentException` when trying to new up the StreamWriter, because `m_FileStream` has already been disposed by another thread and is null (`m_StreamWriter` is also null).  How do I put a lock around the member variable?

Comment: where are you assigning m_FileStream  you are creating a null stream it appears.. do you have additional code that you Omitted from your question..?

Comment: where do you create the initial FileStream..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I have it right above (see edit)

Comment: looks like it would still cause error where do you define or pass in m_CurrentFileName..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
class TextLogger : IDisposable
{
    private FileStream m_FileStream;
    private StreamWriter m_StreamWriter;
    private object m_Lock = new object();

    void CreateNewLogFile()
    {
        lock (m_Lock)
        {
            if ( m_FileStream != null )
                m_StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(m_FileStream);
        };
    }

    void CalledFromOtherThread()
    {
        //Do stuff

        lock (m_Lock)
        {
            if (m_FileStream != null)
                m_FileStream.Dispose();
            m_FileStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When `CalledFromOtherThread` is called from another thread it should acquire the lock and then dispose the m_FileStream. This way in `CreateNewLogFile` you will never have a disposed FileStream

Comment: So the caller should be responsible for calling dispose?

Comment: Whoever is calling should acquire the lock. This ensures that your m_FileStream is either **null or valid**

Answer (score 1):

The [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) is better

```
 static void Main()
    {
        // Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
        ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
        {
            return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        });

        // Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
        Action action = () =>
        {
            // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the
            // first action to run on this thread.
            bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;

            Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
        };

        // Launch eight of them.  On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames
        Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

        // Dispose when you are done
        ThreadName.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `IDisposable` object instance has been disposed of by its `Dispose()` method being called, the object reference is — or should be — no longer usable as its internal state has been destroyed pending garbage collection.

You should instantiate a new object instance rather than trying to reuse the existing object instance.

A well-crafted object should throw a specific subtype of [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) when any operation is performed on a disposed object: [ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx) (with the possible exception of post-disposal invocations of `Dispose()`.)

The documentation for [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) has in the community content section a good example of a thread-safe implementation for [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).